# AS3 AIR Socket based app status reporting?

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, air, terminal

How do I go about creating a socket based status reporting system for an AIR app?

What I have in mind, is you connect to the app via socket connection with some sort of terminal. It presents you with a list of options, you issue commands back, and it reports back any stats and messages.

(This is for an app running on a remote kiosk, connected via 3G.)

Comment: I found various chat type implementations, what I didn't find was any automated type apps - and this is where I was hoping for a little direction

Comment: I agree with asMan, this isn't anything special I mean this is literally the most basic implementation of and fundamental concept of a socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ServerSocket and listen for connections. Add the onConnect listener to tell when a client has connected and use the ProgressEvent to tell when the client has sent data over the socket. Here are two tutorials and an excerpt on how to get started with a ServerSocket:

```
import flash.net.ServerSocket;
import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;

private function onConnect(e:ServerSocketConnectEvent):void
{
    var incomingSocket:Socket = e.socket;
    // You can now read and write data from the socket instance
}
var server:ServerSocket = new ServerSocket();
server.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, onConnect);
server.bind(8888); // Pass in the port number you want to listen on
server.listen();
```

[Basic](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/creating_socket_server.html).

[More complex example which accepts client data transfer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html#includeExamplesSummary).

Comment: great thank you, I hadn't come across that article. Its all making a little more sense now.

Comment: Using a simple switch statement on the incoming message I can easily accomplish my goal now. thanks.